# chess design issue

Tags: c++

Look at this example

```
 class Player {
        ChessEngine* ce;
    public:
        makeMove() {
            ce.addMove();
        }
    };

    class ChessEngine {
        Player* p1;
         list<move*> moveList;
    public:
        ChessEngine() {
            p1 = new Player;
        }
        Player* getPlayer() {
            return p1;
        }
        void addMove() {

        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        ChessEngine chessEngine1;
        return 0;
    }
```

I have restructured the problem so that it can be understood.
Here ChessEngine knows about Player to call makeMove.

Player  needs to call addMove of object  chessEngine.
My problem is how ****ChessEngine * ce attribute of class Player*** can be initialised as  pointer to object chessEngine1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by adding constructor to `Player`:

```
Player(ChessEngine * _ce) : ce(_ce) {}
```

and passing `ChessEngine` as a parameter:

```
ChessEngine() {
    p1 = new Player(this);
}
```